# websocket connection fails after adding Content-Security-Policy in nginx

Tags: nginx, websocket, content-security-policy

I want to add a new header Content-Security-Policy to my nginx conf in order to improve security. I've added all external sources and everything works fine except for the chatbot which is infobip. It uses wss protocol and for some reason I can't find the right way to configure it.

[This is the error that I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An2cU.png)

And this is my the header in nginx.conf

add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' wss:  wss://*.infobip.com ws://*.infobip.com *.infobip.com   http://www.w3.org https://fonts.googleapis.com https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com *.youtube.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/; img-src 'self' data: https://*.openstreetmap.org wss://livechat-fr.infobip.com/chat/web/proxy/827/toxgylwd/websocket always; connect-src 'self' wss: ws: wss://*.infobip.com ws://*.infobip.com *.infobip.com https://*.doubleclick.net wss://livechat-fr.infobip.com/chat/web/proxy/492/hybzmnjl/websocket 'unsafe-inline' always;";

I've tried numerous ways to allow the websocket connection but none seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 issues:

1. Console errors you shown are not CSP-related. "403 Forbidden" means you do not have access to related Url. "'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'" means you try to embed iframe but that page disallows embedding via `X-Frame-Options: "DENY"` HTTP header.
2. Wrong format of Nginx `add_header`. It should looks like (pay attention to quotes - `always` keyword should be placed out of the CSP settings):

   `add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'..." always;`
3. [Wrong](http://csplite.com/csp/check/?pl=eJyVUUFqwzAQ%2FIrRxVCIBE5KW%2BnYeyn0BbK8stXIWmGto7ilf6%2FtlJAEWuhlQTOzy8xIy638TPNg1h2ZelFJ3kvm4QCeKScrtXLPb69sYaqdZA1YPXrapMEUZQJvy6IcQ9IWNi54F6AsckpyHUJwFyzWLnKD%2FQzdIlePjijOgpwzz1uOQ7siy47FQIm3iK0HHV06yxcykTb7qKnjNSIlGnQ0TTidn3CksYYr%2FUK%2Bpwa8Oww8AAlVuL69zNNo0vKs5xghzGcBqNdx9XXKNh8A02na2OEyh1gwkaEWccDjJB6rB0F4bCefmwVOaPZAhfZZT0kVBkMAc9XnT3%2B%2Fd3j3d4nrUoNj7cF4Z%2FZLyv953j1Vopvqjz68%2BwvPNx%2BtmPr6BjcFynE%3D#result) format of CSP's host-sources. Host-sources like `.youtube.com` must not contain a leading `.` dot:
   `youtube.com` will allow to load resources from *http(s)://youtube.com* and `*.youtube.com` will allow resources from the subdomains of *youtube.com*.

So your syntactically correct CSP should looks like:

`add_header Content-Security-Policy "\`
  `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com\`
    `https://fonts.googleapis.com infobip.com ws://infobip.com wss://infobip.com youtube.com\`
    `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net http://www.w3.org;\`
  `connect-src 'self' infobip.com wss://infobip.com ws://*.infobip.com\`
    `wss://livechat-fr.infobip.com/chat/web/proxy/ https://doubleclick.net;\`
  `img-src 'self' data: https://openstreetmap.org;\`
`" always;`

Note that:

- wss://livechat-fr.infobip.com/chat/web/proxy/**492/hybzmnjl/websocket** - do not include bold path-part to CSP, because it's changed each time.
- The scheme-sources like `wss:` covers any host-sources with that scheme (eg *wss://site.com/websocket*). So I deleted the scheme-sources and left the host-sources.
- I deleted some unsupported sources, for instance `'unsafe-inline'` in the `connect-src`.
- Nginx should support a backslash `\` as line break, so I used it because it's hard to maintain CSP in one line. Check does your Nginx version supports this feature.

**Note 2:** This CSP can block some sources - just add them to the appropriate directives.

**Note 3:** Consider moving the sources from the `default-src` directive to the `script-src` + `style-src` + `font-src` directives. Because for now you actually allows `'unsafe-inline'` in the `scrit-src` so your CSP does not protect against XSS. It will also be difficult to manage CSP in the future, since the sources are mixed in one directive.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I still get the same error - WebSocket connection to ... failed. I also get: Refused to display 'https://livechat-fr.infobip.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
This is the how I've set up the header     add_header  'X-Frame-Options' "SAMEORIGIN" always;

Comment: You set `X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"` on your server but `livechat-fr.infobip.com` blocked is not served by your server. It's `livechat-fr.infobip.com` publishes `X-Frame-Options "DENY"` header to prevent embedding. You may have configured something incorrectly in your `infobip.com` account.

Comment: The issue is solved. The CSP directive works fine. It turned out that the corporate network was blocking traffic from/to infobip and I hadn't been informed about that. Thank you again for your effort, still helped me set the directive tough.

Answer (score 1):

Since every websocket connection start by a regular http request, you must add a CSP for https://your-websocket-server-domain:port

The http request will be answered with a `101: swtiching protocols` and then the connection will become a WebSocket connection.

Note that I don't think that the ws: or wss: csp directive is required at all.